# Can I Develop Java Web Applications On Ubuntu 14.04 And Use My Apache Server To View Them?

Tags: java, linux, apache, ubuntu, server

It may sound like a noobie question, but all I want to know is how to install java on ubuntu, does Apache support Java Web Applications, and What other resources I need.

Answer (score 1):

Apache isn't typically used to run Java applications.

If you want the Apache project most typically used for Java on the web, you should take a look at [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).  Tomcat is it's own web server, separate from Apache.

In some configurations, Apache is used in front of or besides an install of Tomcat to serve static content; images, for example.

For installing Tomcat on Ubuntu, it should be pretty easy:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Then check http://localhost:8080, which is where it serves by default.

Comment: Can, uh, someone explain why they downvoted me?  Is something incorrect, or what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First check that java is not already installed by typing "java -version" in a console. If java is installed it will print out the version. To install java run the following

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

This will install openJDK.

There are many web application frameworks you can use with Java. One of the more popular ones is the play framework. you can grab it here https://www.playframework.com/

and there are installation instructions for Apache here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/HTTPServer

Comment: I have apache, but I need to know if I have to configure anything to run java. Do I need to use CGI or anything like that, or does it work out of the box?

Comment: You can use **groovy** language to develop web applications for java platform, which use apache tomcat to run it as WAR file, you can setup apache tomcat and groovy environment on ubuntu  (http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/11/06/how-to-install-groovy-2-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-lts-32-64bit-linux-easy-guide/)